# Unexpected string when reading <img> images from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I am trying to get images from a Firebase Storage into a table, and the links to each image are given as a Child in a Firebase Database. By following many of the SE recommendations, I finally got a code that can convert images from from gs:// to http://. By using `alert(url)`, I can see the image link that can potentially be inserted in a `<img>`, but I can't manage to make it show as an image object. What am I doing wrong in the code? Can anyone help me to elucidate this?

In the code below, *imageUrl* contains the gs:// code

```js
< script >
var events = firebase.database();
var storage = firebase.storage();

events.ref("-Events").orderByKey().limitToLast(10).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    var content = '';
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      var val = data.val();
      var link = val.imageUrl;
      var storageRef = storage.refFromURL(link).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        var test = url;
        alert(url);
        document.querySelector('img').src = test;
        alert(test);
      }).catch(function(error) {});
      content += '<tr>';
      content += '<td>' + val.imageUrl + '</td>';
      content += '<td>' + '<img src="storageRef.url" alt='
      ' border=3 height=100 width=100>' + '</td>';
      content += '</tr>';

    });
    $('#ex-table').append(content);

    var tbody = $('table tbody');
    tbody.html($('tr', tbody).get().reverse());
  }
});

<
/script>
```

Comment: I assume that it's this line that's supposed to put the image URL into the image element: `document.querySelector('img').src = test;`. When you put a breakpoint on that line, does `document.querySelector('img')` give you the right element?

Comment: Yes. It gives me the right link. The problem can be partially solved by replacing ``<img src="storageRef.url"`` to ``<img src=storageRef.url``, but all the pictures overcrowd in the same first <img>. I would guess that it is because of the way <img> is defined. Any idea what else can be wrong in the code?